# How to add datepicker and timepicker to Django forms.SplitDateTimeField?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, django-crispy-forms

I have a form that splits the date and time from a datetime field in the model.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model   = MyModel
        fields  = ('name', 'description', 'start', 'end',)
        widgets = {
            'start': forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(),
            'end': forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(),
            }
```

How can I add a datepicker and timepicker to each separate input box that is rendered?

Setting:

```
'start': forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```

makes both inputs datepicker but I need the second one to be a timepicker..

I am using Django 2.0, bootstrap and crispy forms

Answer (score 5):

forms.SplitDateTimeWidget() renders an Html input that may contain some attributes that you will need in your template:

```
forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(attrs={'attrs': 'attrs'})`.
# You don't need to edit the "input:type", type text is good
```

The rendering will be something like that

```
<input type='text' name='field_name_0' id='id_field_name_0' attrs='attrs'>
<input type='text' name='field_name_1' id='id_field_name_1' attrs='attrs'>
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#SplitDateTimeWidget), **New in Django 2.***
You can add seperate attributes.

```
# Free to add attributes that you want
'start': forms.SplitDateTimeWidget(
    date_attrs({'class':'datepicker'}), # or override the ID, "id":id
    time_attrs({'class':'timepicker'}),
)
```

Since I do not know what kind of **Datetime** neither **Timepicker** that you use in your project. So, in your `js` call each of them by their conventional name `class`...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
$(".timepicker").timepicker();
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add: date_attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}, time_attrs={'class': 'timepicker'},)

Comment: yes, based on the `datetime` & `timepicker` class to trigger what you use